# How to fix jagged lines on my LCD screen

Tags: display, lcd, visual-artifacts

I have not used my computer for about one week. When I start my PC, the screen starts displaying some sort of artifacts on the screen. I have found the correct issue naming "Vertical Jagged Lines" here on website: http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01608578

[image]

[image]

I have no knowledge in electronics - How would you suggest me to proceed by myself ? What should I do first ?

I believe there is some kind of check-steps to follow to investigate the issue.

Thank you

**==== WHAT I'VE DONE SO FAR ====**

- Video cards are fine - image is working well on other screens
- Issue persists even while having no screen cables (dvi,hdmi,...) plugged in

**==== TEARDOWN ====**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I think the problem comes somewhere from this area (where the TOP cables are connected to the screen)

[image]

AND HERE IS THE PHOTO WHEN THE CABLES ARE DISCONNECTED FROM THE LCD, SO LCD SCREEN IS ON AND THERE IS NO ARTIFACT LINES...probably it's the faulty cables ?

[image]

Comment: Please post a photo depicting the lines in question.

Comment: @gronostaj - I've updated my questions with some informations and photos

Comment: Looks like the screen is physically damaged. Try to hook up another PC or laptop and check if lines are still there.

Comment: @gronostaj - they are still there even when it's connected to another computer. I can't dissassembly the monitor to check the cables inside. I don't know how to tear it down.

Comment: Try and apply pressure directly above or below the lines by pinching the frame from the front and back. If the lines go away, it is likely a loose connection on the LCD panel. While not directly fixable, you may be able to work around the issue with a bulldog clip until you can replace the monitor.

Comment: @MichaelFrank - already tried that, but nothing happens. Also I've tried to press on each area of the screen and the frame itself, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in chat, here is an answer version of my previous comment:

This issue is likely a loose connection on the LCD. I would suggest applying direct pressure front to back above (or below) the 'jagged lines'. If the problem is minimised or goes away, a temporary solution can reached by attaching a [bulldog clip](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/37/Bulldog_Clip_2.jpg/220px-Bulldog_Clip_2.jpg) to the bezel of the damaged area.

This won't be a permanent fix, and it may reduce in effectiveness over time. But it should be enough to keep your monitor functional until a replacement can be obtained.

Obviously, if the monitor is under any kind of warranty it should be returned to the manufacturer or place of purchase.

**CAUTION:** I can't guarantee this *will* fix the issue. It may even make it worse, but it's not like the monitor is reliable at the moment anyway.

Comment: unfortunately nothing happend while I was applying a presure above each areas. I would like to take a look inside but have no access nor manual how to open/dissassembly the monitor to check out cables.

Comment: can you check please the new photos I've uploaded and tell me if there something wrong ? I think everything is fine

Comment: @aspirinemaga I can't tell anything from those pictures. The issue is probably not with the cabling from the PCB to the monitor, but rather the LCD panel itself.

Comment: Check the last picture. I've disconnected the cables from the backend chip, and the LCD screen remains powered on, and the artifacts are gone. so maybe the issue is in those cables ? (TOP white cables)

Comment: Try reattaching each white ribbon individually, see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already checked the GPU, the issue is with the display.

The problem is either with the video connection (on the outside), or with the image processor (on the inside).

I remember baking a Samsung monitor that was giving some issues just like this. This is obviously going to void any warranty, but you can remove the image processing board from the other parts in display, and place the board in an oven.

There's videos of this on YouTube (DIY Monitor Repair), but what the baking does is "resolder" connections on the board. The Samsung monitor I was dealing with was made when the company was changing over from Lead to Lead-Less solder. I found that it works for a year or more, then needs another good bake.

Comment: Quite a few monitor manufactures use plastic clips, and it can be quite a system to figure out how the clips detach. The saving grace of plastic is that it has give, it will bend if stressed. Downside is that it can still break. I would suggest a search for videos on DIY monitor repairs as many explain how to deal with the pesky clips. The intention and design was for them to go on, and rarely come off.

Comment: Ok, i've managed to open it. please check the images of the updated questions

Comment: @aspirinemaga Either it is the cables, or the image board itself. Try re-seating the cables, or continue on and bake the image processing board (2nd last image). Again, it has been a while since I have done this, but I remember using a temp around 350 degrees F for several minutes and letting it sit outside the oven for several minutes afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like LCD display inside your monitor is physically damaged. Fixing it probably isn't worth it, so your best bet is to buy a new screen.

Comment: is it normal that it just damages by itself ? i didn't even touch it, nor drop or something like that

Comment: I've seen it happening with old screens (8+ years), but usually it's a result of pressure applied to screen surface. Anyway, there isn't much serviceable stuff inside a LCD monitor, once it starts malfunctioning it's time to replace it (with the exception of failing backlight, which can often be fixed by replacing lamps or transistors, but that's a different story)